# Edit Mobile Version CSS with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In my bootstrap 3 navbar, the elements other than the brand which is on the left are floated to the right using the "pull-right" bootstrap class. In the mobile version, when they are dropped down with the toggle button, they remain floated to the right which looks very ugly. How can I change it so they are either floated left or centered when in the mobile view? Thanks in advance for any help

```
    <div class="container" id="main">

<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">

        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" ><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse navbar-right">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li> <a href="#">Our Mission</a><li>
                    <li> <a href="#">What We Do </a><li>
                    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a><li>
                </ul> <!-- end nav ul -->

            </div> <!-- end nav collapse -->

        </div><!--  end nav container -->


</div><!-- end navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

instade of using `pull-right` ..use `navbar-right` and lets see if it works.. it should work ;)

**Update:**
Use this

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li> <a href="#">Our Mission</a><li>
                <li> <a href="#">What We Do </a><li>
                <li> <a href="#">About Us</a><li>
            </ul> <!-- end nav ul -->

        </div>
```

Comment: I tried doing that and that simply removed the float completely. I added the code so you have an idea of what Im doing. Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: i just update my answer with the code that you have to replace .. i believe you used `pull-right` in working place :)

Comment: When I added the pull-right property to the UL it worked. Not sure why the navbar-right didn't though.  Thanks a lot

Comment: `navbar-right`  should work .. it will give you nice navigation than `pull-right` .any way if you found the solution then please mark this answer,so that other will know if they have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define the button as a pull-left instead of pull-right? Maybe that suits to you.